# Runtime.getRuntime().exec returns empty string

Tags: java, command-line, process, inputstream, runtime.exec

This is the code I use:

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec("cmd /C cd C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/semantics/semantics/bin");
    process = runtime.exec("java test \"abc\" \"def\"");
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = "", tmp;

    while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line += tmp;
    }

    System.out.println(line);
```

I tried to use commands such as "cmd /C dir" and i got a proper return value.

And this is my test application :

```
import semantics.Compare;
public class USAGE {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
String a = args[0];
String b = args[1];
Compare c = new Compare(a,b);
System.out.println(c.getResult());
}
}
```

Comment: Does your `test` application print anything to standard out?

Comment: I edited my question, please recheck it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the working directory of a process you start with Runtime.exec, use the version that takes File as one of the parameters.

The working directory is private to the process, it cannot be changed by running a "cd" command in a different process.

Comment: You can pass null, it means the subprocess will inherit the environment from the current process. You'll probably find the ProcessBuilder class easier to use though.